# javascript output return to console

Tags: javascript, console

When I do a `return` in the console, Why does it output to the screen? I'm using chrome, but it probably does this in Firefox also. Is it assuming the console is the caller and there's a built-in function that echos the returned value?

```
function mike() {return "fsadf";}
mike()
"fsadf"
```

Comment: it doesn't output to the screen for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More generally, it echoes the value of the entered expression, for example writing `5+5` in console and pressing enter would echo `10`.

For reasoning, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop

Answer (score 1):

It's a feature of the console (or rather, the UI that surrounds it - sometimes there's a separate input field) that typing in a JavaScript expression will evaluate that expression and display the result.  It can be very useful for debugging!